# use EventListener to display submit button when a form is filled

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, event-listener

I'm a beginner in `javascript` and we where given a task at uni to create a `hangman game` using `input fields` inside an `html form` . I want to use an `event listener` to display a `submit` button when `all the input fields are filled` and whenever I want to delete a letter the button must obviously go away .
I have written code below that displays input fields in a form container depending on the letter size of the give word `(ex. word = "hi" => 2 input fields to fill for "hi" )`.My problem is that I have no clue how to create this eventListener function and I would appreciate your help with this .

My code :

```js
function hangman(){
    var island = "Rhodes"; //the given word that is supposed to be found 
    var t = document.createTextNode(shuffleWord(island))
    document.getElementById("hidden-word").appendChild(t);
    createSpaces(island);
}

function shuffleWord (word){
    var shuffledWord = '';
    word = word.split('');
    while (word.length > 0) {
      shuffledWord +=  word.splice(word.length * Math.random() << 0, 1);
    }
    return shuffledWord;
}


function createSpaces(text){
    for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
      var space = document.createElement("input");
      space.setAttribute("class" , "dash");
      document.getElementById("hangman-container").appendChild(space);
    }
}
```

```css
body, html {
    background-size: cover;
}

body{
    margin: 0;

}


.transparent-box{
    border:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:15%;
    background-color:black;
    height:500px;
    width:70%;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.transparent-box p{
    color:white;  
    text-align:center;

}

.transparent-box h1{
    color:white;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    top:30px;
}


#hangman-container{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width:auto;
    top:30%;
    left:0%;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}


.dash{
    margin:0;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width:5%;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 5%;
    background-color: turquoise;
    color:red;
    font-size:30px;
}

.dash:focus{
    opacity:0.8;
}

#submitbtn{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top:200%;
    left:80%;
    float:right; 
}
```

```html
<body onload=hangman()>

        <div class = "transparent-box" id = "t-box">
            <p>Play here </p>
            <h1 id = "hidden-word">The word is : </h1> 
            <form id  = "hangman-container" method="POST">
                <button type = "submit" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
            </form>  
        </div>
         
    
    


</body>
```

The word is given as a random string and you have to guess the correct word in the above code .
Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this fiddle, where I am going through all input fields and adding a listener, then inside that go through each field and based upon it's content I show or hide the submit button.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/zd3rqsnh/25/)

```js
const inputLists = document.querySelectorAll("input");
let showButton = true;
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((el) => {

  el.addEventListener('input', (evt => {

    inputLists.forEach((ip) => {
      console.log(ip.value);
      if (ip.value === '') {
        showButton = false;
      } else {
        showButton = true;
      }
    })
    if (showButton) {
      document.querySelector('button').style.display = 'block'
    } else {
      document.querySelector('button').style.display = 'none'
    }
  }))
})
```

```css
button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I doubt OP can change their code into yours. Also you have a boolean. Use it to toggle the button instead of using an if. Also why loop all the way if there is something empty? It is very complicated code for such a simple issue

Comment: Here is a neater version https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2sm0dpjr/

Comment: @Asutosh I added your code in mine in <body> as a <srcipt> and it didn't work.I am checking this further

Comment: @Asutosh could you explain this line to me ? I am a beginner just to make sure I understand .          const showButton = [...inputLists].filter(ip => ip.value.trim() !== '').length === inputLists.length;

Comment: inputLists contains all the input fields, then filter it to find which contains non empty string, if the filtered list's length matches to inputLists's length, that means all the input boxes are filed. This comparision logic's value is assigned to showButton

Answer (score 1):

You likely want this

1. addEventListener on the window.load
2. addEventListener on the letters
3. toggle the class
4. Note I added a hide class to the button to turn it off

   ```js
   function hangman() {
     var island = "Rhodes"; //the given word that is supposed to be found 
     var t = document.createTextNode(shuffleWord(island))
     document.getElementById("hidden-word").appendChild(t);
     createSpaces(island);
   }

   function shuffleWord(word) {
     var shuffledWord = '';
     word = word.split('');
     while (word.length > 0) {
       shuffledWord += word.splice(word.length * Math.random() << 0, 1);
     }
     return shuffledWord;
   }

   function createSpaces(text) {
     for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
       var space = document.createElement("input");
       space.setAttribute("class", "dash");
       document.getElementById("hangman-container").appendChild(space);
     }
   }

   window.addEventListener("load",function() { // on page load
     document.getElementById("t-box").addEventListener("input",function(e) { // any input in the t-box
       const tgt = e.target; // the actual input 
       if (tgt.classList.contains("dash")) { // is it a "dash"?
         const letters = [...document.querySelectorAll(".dash")]; // get all dash
         length = letters.filter(inp => inp.value.trim() !=="").length; // filter on filled in
         document.getElementById("submitbtn").classList.toggle("hide",length<letters.length); // toggle hide class if filled
       }
     })
     hangman()
   });
   ```

   ```css
   body,
   html {
     background-size: cover;
   }

   body {
     margin: 0;
   }

   .transparent-box {
     border: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 10%;
     left: 15%;
     background-color: black;
     height: 500px;
     width: 70%;
     opacity: 0.6;
   }

   .transparent-box p {
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
   }

   .transparent-box h1 {
     color: white;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 20px;
     top: 30px;
   }

   #hangman-container {
     display: block;
     position: relative;
     width: auto;
     top: 30%;
     left: 0%;
     background-color: transparent;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: space-evenly;
   }

   .dash {
     margin: 0;
     align-items: flex-start;
     width: 5%;
     border: none;
     border-radius: 5%;
     background-color: turquoise;
     color: red;
     font-size: 30px;
   }

   .dash:focus {
     opacity: 0.8;
   }

   #submitbtn {
     position: absolute;
     top: 200%;
     left: 80%;
     float: right;
   }
   .hide { display:none}
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="transparent-box" id="t-box">
       <p>Play here </p>
       <h1 id="hidden-word">The word is : </h1>
       <form id="hangman-container" method="POST">
         <button type="submit" class="hide" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
       </form>
     </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This one contains another feature. When one field is filled, it gets to the next one automaticly. Good luck.

```js
var island;

function hangman(){
    island = "Rhodes"; //the given word that is supposed to be found 
    var t = document.createTextNode(shuffleWord(island))
    document.getElementById("hidden-word").appendChild(t);
    createSpaces(island);
}

function shuffleWord (word){
    var shuffledWord = '';
    word = word.split('');
    while (word.length > 0) {
      shuffledWord +=  word.splice(word.length * Math.random() << 0, 1);
    }
    return shuffledWord;
}


function createSpaces(text){
    var spaces = new Array(island.length);
    for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
      let n=i;
      spaces[i] = document.createElement("input");
      spaces[i].setAttribute("class" , "dash");
      spaces[i].maxLength = 1;
      spaces[i].oninput = function () {
        if (this.length == 0) return;
        if (n == island.length-1) document.getElementById("submitbtn").classList.add("show");
        if (n < island.length-1) spaces[n+1].focus();
      }
      document.getElementById("hangman-container").appendChild(spaces[i]);
    }
}
```

```css
body, html {
    background-size: cover;
}

body{
    margin: 0;

}


.transparent-box{
    border:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:15%;
    background-color:black;
    height:500px;
    width:70%;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.transparent-box p{
    color:white;  
    text-align:center;

}

.transparent-box h1{
    color:white;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    top:30px;
}


#hangman-container{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width:auto;
    top:30%;
    left:0%;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}


.dash{
    margin:0;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width:5%;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 5%;
    background-color: turquoise;
    color:red;
    font-size:30px;
}

.dash:focus{
    opacity:0.8;
}

#submitbtn{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top:200%;
    left:80%;
    float:right; 
}
#submitbtn.show {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body onload=hangman()>

        <div class = "transparent-box" id = "t-box">
            <p>Play here </p>
            <h1 id = "hidden-word">The word is : </h1> 
            <form id  = "hangman-container" method="POST">
                <button type = "submit" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
            </form>  
        </div>
         
    
    


</body>
```

Comment: You cannot change the letter easily if you regret the letter. I guess that is ok since hangman normally does not allow you to backtrack. You could make the previous letter readonly

Comment: That's your opinion. But I think my code makes more sense to the user. I was about to write it on your way but then I thought this would be better.